# jQuery find and replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text contained on a `<textarea>` like this:

```
Hi {nom},

We are glad to accept your invitation.
```

I need it to become

```
Hi Dolly Parton,

We are glad to accept your invitation.
```

I don't want to use any plugin, but I have tried developing this simple functionality with no possitive result:

```
prevContent=$('textarea').val(); //alerts correctly textarea content
content = prevContent.replace('{nom}','Dolly Parton');
```

In this case, no replacement is made and content has the same value as prevContent.

This is not meant to make a real time replacemet, it has to be replaced before submitting form:

```
 $(document).on('click','.submitMessage', function(){
        prevContent=$('textarea').val();    
        content = prevContent.replace('{nom}','Dolly Parton');

        $.post('../actions/newMessage.php',{ms_content:content}).success(

                    function(data){
                        alert("yikes");}
   );}
});
```

SOLVED: This was due to a spell mistake on variable. It was sent like {nom1}, not {nom}. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

You need use `RegExp` with [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) flag, because in your example only first `{nom}` will be replaced:

```
var prevContent = $('textarea').val();
var content     = prevContent.replace(/\{nom\}/g, 'Dolly Parton');
```

and to update `textarea` you can use `.val`, like so

```
$('textarea').val(content);
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/f1sew59x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to assign value of "content" to textarea, as :

```
$('textarea').val(content);
```

Comment: @Biomehanika you are posting data in 'prevContent'? if so then assign the value of content to prevContent OR Post 'content' only.

Comment: prevContent= "Hi {nom}". content must be="Hi Dolly Parton"